# Get the records between two dates

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

I have a table called **Billing** which contains the below columns

```
id| resource_name | start_date | end_date | total_amount
```

This table is populated with data for different resource with different start_date and end_dates. I need to retrieve the data from the tables.

### Sample Record

```
id| resource_name | start_date          | end_date            | total_amount
1 | abc           | 2018-09-15 03:00:00 | 2018-09-15 04:00:00 | 20
```

If I write a query like this it will return the above result

```
select * from billing where start_date >= '2018-09-15 03:00:00' and end_date <= '2018-09-15 04:00:00'
```

But the below doesn't

```
select * from billing where start_date >= '2018-09-15 03:00:00' and end_date <= '2018-09-15 03:30:00'
```

Is there any way to retrieve the same . I am using Django ORM to do the same

Comment: how will the record return where the time is 4 and you are giving 3.30 , so it wont match,

Comment: @Exprator Yes I know . I am checking if there is any function which will help me to do this. Instead of using <=

Comment: no you cant do that with any function giving 3.30 where 4 is greater

Answer (score 1):

you can use the django filter method.

```
Billing.objects.filter(start_date__gte='2018-09-15 03:00:00', end_date__lte='2018-09-15 03:30:00')
```

Comment: This is the query what I was using. But this will not give the correct answer. Please refer the sample data which I have provided and query which doesnt return the answer

Answer (score 0):

It's a little confusing from your question, but if you are trying to get all orders that overlap at all with the time period specified, you need to modify the query a bit:

```
Billing.objects.filter(start_date__lte='2018-09-15 03:30:00', end_date__gt='2018-09-15 03:00:00')
```

No, that's not written incorrectly. You need to reverse the dates and gte/lte from your original query.

```
IE: Billing.objects.filter(start_date__lte='the end datetime of your time period', end_date__gt='the start datetime of your time period')
```

This will ensure that any order that overlaps at all with the 03:00 to 03:30 block is included. All of these will be included:

```
id| resource_name | start_date          | end_date            | total_amount
1 | abc           | 2018-09-15 03:00:00 | 2018-09-15 04:00:00 | 20
2 | abd           | 2018-09-15 02:00:00 | 2018-09-15 03:00:01 | 20
3 | abe           | 2018-09-01 03:00:00 | 2018-09-20 04:00:00 | 20
4 | abf           | 2018-09-15 03:10:00 | 2018-09-15 03:20:00 | 20
```

But the following won't:

```
id| resource_name | start_date          | end_date            | total_amount
5 | abg           | 2018-09-15 02:00:00 | 2018-09-15 03:00:00 | 20
6 | abh           | 2018-09-15 03:30:01 | 2018-09-15 04:00:00 | 20
```

If you're looking for orders that are exclusively within your time period, use Aman Kumar's answer.

Comment: Thanks for replaying . Your solution works for some scenario. But it will fail in some scenarios

Comment: Which scenarios? Please explain further, because the code does exactly what I said it does.

If the dates you selected overlap at all with the Billing object instance's start_date and end_date, they will be returned. This includes date ranges that start before start_date or end after end_date, as long as a portion of the date range falls within the dates you have selected.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the pgsql solution. But not sure how to convert the same into Django ORM

```
SELECT *  FROM billing_lines  WHERE (start_date, end_date) OVERLAPS ('2018-09-15 03:00:00', '2018-09-15 03:30:00');
```