# Pgsql overlap function in Django

Tags: django, postgresql

I am working on project where I need to pull the date from a table based on startdate and enddate. Here is the query

```
SELECT *  FROM billing_lines  WHERE (start_date, end_date) OVERLAPS ('2018-09-15 03:00:00', '2018-09-15 03:30:00');
```

I know i can use `raw()` to execute the above query. But my question is , How to convert this into Django ORM query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ranges *[a<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>1</sub>)* and *[a<sub>2</sub>, b<sub>2</sub>)* do *not* overlap if *a<sub>1</sub>≥b<sub>2</sub>*, or *b<sub>1</sub>≤a<sub>2</sub>*. We can negate this expression to know when two intervals overlap: *a<sub>1</sub><b<sub>2</sub>*, and *b<sub>1</sub>>a<sub>2</sub>*.

Here `start_date` and `end_date` are *a<sub>1</sub>* and *b<sub>1</sub>* respectively, and the two values you wrote `'2018-09-15 03:00:00'` and `'2018-09-15 03:30:00'` are thus *a<sub>2</sub>* and *b<sub>2</sub>* respectively.

We can thus make a query like:

```
begin='2018-09-15 03:00:00'
end='2018-09-15 03:30:00'

Lines.objects.filter(
    start_date__lt=end
    end_date__gt=begin
)
```

This thus does *not* check if the `(begin, end)` is "contained" in the `(start_date, end_date)`, it checks if there is at least one element that is a member of both ranges.

Now the [`OVERLAP` function in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-datetime.html) is a bit more complicated, since it automatically swaps the times in case the `end_date` is greater than the `start_date`, so we might need to use `.annotate(..)` here:

```
from django.db.models import F
from django.db.models.functions import Greatest, Least

begin='2018-09-15 03:00:00'
end='2018-09-15 03:30:00'

Lines.objects.annotate(
    d0=Least(F('start_date'), F('end_date')),
    d1=Greatest(F('start_date'), F('end_date')),
).filter(
    d0__lt=end
    d1__gt=begin
)
```

This is still not exactly the same, since if `d0` and `d1` are the same, then the range is "inclusive", so we should consider this case as well:

```
Lines.objects.annotate(
    d0=Least(F('start_date'), F('end_date')),
    d1=Greatest(F('start_date'), F('end_date')),
).filter(
    Q(d0__lt=end, d1__gt=begin) |
    Q(d0=F('d1'), d0__gte=begin, d0__lt=end)
)
```

It also requires to "prepare" the `begin` and `end` (you should make sure that `begin <= end`, and if not swap these, not because otherwise the method will fail, but because these are the "exact" specifications of the rather complicated `OVERLAP` function).

Comment: Just curious to know  What in case if the end date is null ?

Comment: @Anish: If `NULL` means "open interval" (well this is a matter of interpretation), then you should rewrite the `start_date__lt=end` to `(Q(start_date__lt=end) | Q(start_date__isnull=True))` and similar for `end_date`.

Comment: yeah . I got it . Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
YourModel.objects.filter(start_date__gte='2018-09-15 03:00:00',end_date__lte='2018-09-15 03:30:00')
```

this should do what you are looking for. Just replace your model name with the dummy provided.

Comment: This query works only if I have  a record which has starting date 2018-09-15 03:00:00 and enddate = 2018-09-15 03:00:00 in the database. Please check the below link it will more idea about what I am trying to implement https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52733598/get-the-records-between-two-dates. So I have to use the overlap query to make it work

Comment: But now you specify that both the `start_date` and `end_date` need to overlap the given time range. It is possible that the two overlap, but that nor the `start_date`, nor the `end_date` overlap, for example because the `start_date` is before `2018-09-15 03:00:00`, and the `end_date` after `2018-09-15 03:30:00`

Comment: @Exprator. Tried the solution. But its throwing error "Unsupported lookup 'overlap' for TimestampField"

Comment: try @WillemVanOnsem solution

Comment: @Exprator: there is a difference between the two, I think yours checks if the (`2018-09-15 03:00:00`, `2018-09-15 03:30:00`) interval is "contained" in the `(start_date, end_date)` range, this is not fully equivalent to "overlapping".